# Probability of 3 x 3 of a kind in a hand of 9.

Tags: probability

This is the card game called Brag. From a standard 52 card deck what are the odds of drawing 9 cards and getting three three-of-a-kinds?

My maths is far too rusty to do anything other than guess that it's whatever the odds of getting one is, raised to the power of 3?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$13 \choose 3$ ways of picking the $3$ card values from the $13$ available. Then, $4 \choose 3$ ways of picking the $3$ suits of the $4$ available for each set of the $3$ sets, so the total number of ways is:

$${13 \choose 3} {4 \choose 3}^3= 18304$$